# Create a tester class in a linked list for showing even numbers

Tags: python, data-structures

This is my node class and Mylist class

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next


class MyList():
    def __init__(self,head=None):
        self.head = head

    def showList(self):
        temp = self.head
        while (temp):
            print(temp.data)
            temp = temp.next
        if self.head is None:
            print("Empty List")
```

This is my showeven number function

```
def showeven(even):
    head = None

    while even:
        if even.data % 2 == 0:
            new_Node = Node(even.data, None)

            if head is None:
                tail = new_Node
                head = new_Node
            else:
                tail.next = new_Node
                tail = new_Node

    MyList(head).showList()
```

Can you guys help me create a tester class or some sort of thing for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply write something like this.

```
def print_even_nodes(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     traverse = self.head                                                                                                                                                            
     while (traverse != None):                                                                                                                                                               
        if (traverse.data % 2 == 0):                                                                                                                                                      
            print(traverse.data)                                                                                                                                                               
        traverse = traverse.next
```

It is pretty much similar to printing the whole singly linked list, the only key difference is that we check if that particular node (`node.data` field) is divisible by 2. If it is true we print out the element else we go to the next node.